# How to get perspective coordinates from file for image overlay with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to do something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APxgPYZOd0I) purely with ffmpeg?

Lets say we have a text file with the frame by frame coordinates for the 4 corners where the image should go. ffmpeg has a [perspective filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html), but how would one get ffmpeg to pull the frame coordinates from the text file? I'm guessing with a pipe of sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `perspective` filter corrects the input's perspective, it doesn't apply a perspective effect. Applied to an overlay it results in a rectangular overlay with a corrected perspective.

The closest you can get with the already implemented filters is via the `frei0r` perspective module.

You can write your own filter for `ffmpeg` or a [frei0r module](https://www.dyne.org/software/frei0r/).

**Update**: using @Mulvya's [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38735921/5726027) you can use [timeline editing](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) with `perspective`:

`perspective=enable='eq(n,0)':x0=...,perspective=enable='eq(n,1)':x0=...`

where `n` is the current frame number.

This will result in an impossibly long command line which may go over the system limit. You're still better writing your own filter.

You can alternatively do one frame at a time with a different command, save the output as an image and re-assemble the video at the end.

Comment: oh right. I was thinking of using the filter_complex blend=all_mode=or, but I'm just learning how to use ffmpeg now

Comment: awesome! Is there a way to get the frame coordinates through a file though?

Comment: @Victor.dMdB file no, but you can technically pass them in the command line, if you must. See updated answer.

Comment: Ok fair enough, you are probably right that the command would go over system limit. I'm looking into how to write a plugin, thanks!

Comment: @aergistal yep, but I'm looking for something to do the whole process in one go